# value always coming back as 0 when the answer should not be 0

Tags: c

Trying to get a value back that usually should return 20 to 30 as `s` with this code

```
int s = sentences / wordcount * 100;
```

both `sentences` and `wordcount` come out as the values they should neither of which are 0. The result of them would be small (0.20 to 0.30) so thinking it might be to do with that?

Comment: Please provide us with the code so that we can try and understand the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try casting the division to a floating point (FP) value explicitly, this should prevent the result of

```
sentences / wordcount
```

from being floored to zero. You should only need to cast one to be a FP value.
Try

```
int s = (double) sentences / wordcount * 100
```

Comment: Just tried this and it was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `sentences` and `wordcount` are `int`s. As result you have integer divisions that is rounded to an integer *before* multiplying by 100. Note that integer division is not commutative.

A simple fix is move multiplication by 100 *before* division by wordcount.

```
int s = sentences * 100 / wordcount;
```

Though the better solution would be using `float` or `double`.

```
float s = (float)sentence / wordcount * 100;
```